# MySQL query returning fewer results when GROUP BY removed

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm having a problem with a query containing a GROUP BY. As part of diagnosing it I removed the GROUP BY statement in order to see the raw data - however when I do that I get *FEWER* rows returned that I do with the GROUP BY.

To reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `date` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
INSERT INTO `test1` VALUES (1312483084,3,2),(1312483084,1,2),(1312483148,1,2),(1312483148,1,2),(1314038654,1,2),(1314301805,1,2);
```

Now run my original SELECT (Complete with GROUP BY):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(from_unixtime(test1.date), from_unixtime(1311801510)) DIV 28 AS date_idx,
min(DATEDIFF(from_unixtime(test1.date), from_unixtime(1311801510))) AS orig_date_idx,            SUM(test1.quantity) AS num_items,
IF(test1.processed in (2,3,4), 'Complete','Pending') as status
FROM test1
GROUP BY status, date_idx \G
```

You should get two rows returned:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     date_idx: 0
orig_date_idx: 8
    num_items: 7
       status: Complete
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     date_idx: 1
orig_date_idx: 29
    num_items: 1
       status: Complete
```

Now remove the GROUP BY, ie:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(from_unixtime(test1.date), from_unixtime(1311801510)) DIV 28 AS date_idx,
min(DATEDIFF(from_unixtime(test1.date), from_unixtime(1311801510))) AS orig_date_idx,            SUM(test1.quantity) AS num_items,
IF(test1.processed in (2,3,4), 'Complete','Pending') as status
FROM test1
```

All of a sudden you only get one row returned - the row that had date_idx == 1 in the original result has been merged into the entry for date_idx == 0

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     date_idx: 0
orig_date_idx: 8
    num_items: 8
       status: Complete
```

All ideas gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly I'm surprised that it runs without just giving you an error for using aggregate functions without a group by, maybe has something to do with the fact that all your fields are calculated values. Anyway, get rid of all your aggregate functions to get to the underlying data.

Comment: Yes - I'm an idiot. Well spotted. Could have sworn that MySQL disallowed aggregate functions without a GROUP BY so it just didn't occur to me :)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are removing the GROUP BY directive makes it unneeded for the execution of the query to subdivide your results on date_idx. The number count is equally going from 1 and 7 in the GROUPED query to 8 in the NON GROUPED query. Without the GROUPBY directive, there is no reason for the query executor to give you more than one row with aggregated information, because you simply did not ask for that seperation.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is an aggregation so is collapsing the rows down for you. However in the case of also using the group by clause, that is taking precedence, with varying data (from the grouping) then being summed. In this case the group by generates two different collections which are then summed. Other data may return different results with the group by.

Comment: Yes - I'm an idiot. Well spotted. Could have sworn that MySQL disallowed aggregate functions without a GROUP BY so it just didn't occur to me :)